# Fibonacci memoization - pass by lvalue vs rvalue reference

Tags: c++, recursion, fibonacci, move-semantics, memoization

I'm learning about memoization and decided to apply this technique to a recursive function calculating the `n`-th Fibonacci number. I am not sure whether I should pass my `memo` map by lvalue reference or rvalue reference. 
Is there any difference (regarding performance and generally how the program behaves) in the two snippets presented below? Which one would be preferred? Also, is there a way to provide a default argument to the first function (`map& memo = map{}` doesn't work because an lvalue reference doesn't bind with an rvalue...)?

**Version #1**

```
using map = std::unordered_map<int, unsigned long long>;
unsigned long long fib(int n, map& memo){
    if(memo.find(n) != memo.cend()) return memo[n];
    if(n <= 2) return 1;
    memo[n] = fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo);
    return memo[n];
}
```

**Version #2**

```
using map = std::unordered_map<int, unsigned long long>;
unsigned long long fib(int n, map&& memo = map{}){
    if(memo.find(n) != memo.cend()) return memo[n];
    if( n <= 2) return 1;
    memo[n] = fib(n - 1, std::move(memo)) + fib(n - 2, std::move(memo));
    return memo[n];
}
```

Comment: Just think about what happens when you move the same thing twice.

Comment: After `std::move(memo)` you are supposed to assume that the contents of `memo` are trash; if they were important then `fib` would need to create a new object to store them.  But your program goes on assuming that it contains something useful, which is contrary to the philosophy of move semantics.

Comment: You should use simple `std::vector` or `std::array` since fibonacci grow extremely fast and  `unsigned long long` will overflow for small index.

Comment: Consider having that `memo` as a `static` local variable, instead of passing it every time. You may also create a `class Fib` with a `memo` member and an accessor member function to retrieve the Fibonacci number.

Comment: @NateEldredge I understand that this is the purpose of `std::move` - to indicate that an object can be "moved from". But is using it the way I did an error? (The program yields correct values for both versions of `fib`).

Comment: @Bob__ Do you mean a function object?

Comment: Also consider a non-recursive solution: the one at the bottom of this page is beautiful! https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference

Comment: Yes, basically, if you just want to overload its `operator()`.

Comment: @Bob__ Thanks, a cool suggestion!

Comment: The second versions works because you use an rvalue reference. It's still a reference. But conceptually this is wrong - you should not be `std::move`ing twice from the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, moving an object corresponds to the following contract:

> I am never planning on using this object again. Person I am moving the object to: you are free to do whatever you'd like with this object's resources. I promise not to use the object again without first assigning it a new value, so I will never see the effects of anything you did. So please, do Cruel and Unusual things to my object if it makes you happy.

Now, consider this line of code:

```
memo[n] = fib(n - 1, std::move(memo)) + fib(n - 2, std::move(memo));
```

Here, you are calling `std::move(memo)`, which signals "I promise never to use `memo` again." However, in the same line of code, you are then assigning to `memo[n]`, which means that you are indeed planning on using `memo` later. That breaks the contract that you're making with whomever you `std::move` the object to. Imagine this as a dialog between you and the calls to Fibonacci:

- You: Hey, Mr. Fibonacci! I got you a memoization table. It's 100% yours and I am never going to use it again.
- Fibonacci: Great! Thanks!
- You: Okay, now that I just gave you the memoization table, I'd like to paint it blue and put flowers on it.
- Fibonacci: Wait, hold on! It's not your table any more!
- You: Well, I'm going to do it anyway.
- Fibonacci: Why, you little! (Violence ensues)

So, yeah. That's not going to work.

Ignoring the assignment to `memo[n]`, there's another issue here. You are trying to move the same object twice to two different people. Think about what that means from the perspective of a conversation between you, the first call to Fibonacci, and the second call to Fibonacci.

- You: Hey, Mr. First Call to Fibonacci! Here's `memo`. It's yours. Do whatever you'd like with it. No one else is going to see it.
- Mr. First Call to Fibonacci: Woohoo! That's awesome!
- You: Hey, Mr. Second Call to Fibonacci! Here's `memo`. It's yours. Do whatever you'd like with it. No one else is going to see it.
- Mr. Second Call to Fibonacci: Woohoo! That's awesome!
- Mr. First Call to Fibonacci: Wait, hold on! They gave *me* that object! They can't give it to you!
- Mr. Second Call to Fibonacci: Weren't you listening? They just gave *me* that object! It's mine!
- Mr. First Call to Fibonacci: Why, you little! (Violence ensues)

So yeah, that isn't going to end well. :-)

Fundamentally, only use `std::move` when you or anyone else is planning on using that object again. In the case of memoization, when a bunch of function calls all need to coordinate to share the same memoization table across the calls, that requirement isn't held, so you shouldn't use rvalue semantics here.